# Nuxt 3: SEO/Meta data from API not visible when sharing link on social media

Tags: nuxt.js, seo, share, social-networking, nuxtjs3

I have a blog in Nuxt 3 and each blog content along with meta data is rendered through api response. The issue is when I share the blog on social media it do not show any meta data that received in API response but only show static meta data which is declared inside `app.vue` file. When I check meta tags through inspect elements tab in broweser dev tools, I can see all required data there.

```
// pages/blog/[slug].vue

<script setup>
import { onMounted, ref, defineProps } from 'vue';
import { useBlogStore } from '~/stores/blog';
import config from '~/app.config.ts'

const route = useRoute()
const blogStore = useBlogStore(); // Create an instance of the blog store
const blog = ref([]);
const { currentRoute } = useRouter();

onMounted(async () => {

  try {
    await blogStore.getBlog(route.params.slug); // Call the getBlogs action
    blog.value = blogStore.$state.blog; // Update the local ref with the fetched data
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }

  useHead({
    title: blog.value.title,
    meta: [
      { name: 'description', content: blog.value.meta_description },
      { name: 'keywords', content: blog.value.keywords },
      { name: 'og:image', content: blog.value.image_url },
      { name: 'og:title', content: blog.value.title },
      { name: 'og:description', content: blog.value.meta_description },
      { name: 'og:type', content: 'article' },
      { name: 'og:url', content: config.web.baseURL + currentRoute.value.fullPath },
      { name: 'twitter:card', content: 'summary_large_image' },
      { name: 'twitter:url', content: config.web.baseURL + currentRoute.value.fullPath },
      { name: 'twitter:title', content: blog.value.title },
      { name: 'twitter:description', content: blog.value.meta_description },
      { name: 'twitter:image', content: blog.value.image_url },
    ],
  })
});
</script>
```

```
// app.vue

<script setup>
  definePageMeta({
    colorMode: 'dark',
  })

  useHead({
    title: 'My Title',
    meta: [
      { name: 'description', content: 'Nuxt app meta description for SEO!' },
      { name: 'theme-color', content: '#000000' },
    ],
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Same problem here. I'm trying to debug with https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ and for both ```useHead()``` and ```useSeoMeta()``` it doesn't show any meta data

Answer (score 0):

I've been through this a couple of times, but then I figure it out. **First** you have to make sure was using the correct composable for fetch the api like useAsyncLazyData and useLazyFetch.

> Read about those here : https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-lazy-async-data

**Second** you could use meta-tag which was provided by nuxt and setup by your needed

> Here about nuxt's meta-tag : https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/seo-meta

For example :

```
<script setup>
// ... import section

definePageMeta({
  hidden: true,
});

const { data, pending } = await useLazyAsyncData(
  `products/${route.params.id}`,
  () =>
    $fetch(`${useRuntimeConfig()?.public.apiUrl}/products/${route.params.id}`, {
      method: "get",
    }),
  {
    transform: (payload) => payload?.result || null,
    watch: false,
  }
);

</script>
<template>
  <div>
    <n-skeleton v-if="pending" type="card" height="250px"></n-skeleton>
    <section v-else>
      <Head>
        <Title>{{ data?.title }}</Title>
        <Meta name="canonical" :content="url.origin" />
        <Meta name="description" :content="data?.description" />
        <Meta name="og:title" :content="data?.title" />
        <Meta name="og:description" :content="data?.description" />
        <Meta name="og:image" :content="data?.client?.picture" />
        <Meta name="twitter:title" :content="data?.title" />
        <Meta name="twitter:description" :content="data?.description" />
        <Meta name="twitter:image" :content="data?.client?.picture" />
        <Meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
      </Head>
      <ClientOnly>
        <molecules-product :data="data" :pending="pending" />
      </ClientOnly>
    </section>
    <br />
    <br />
  </div>
</template>
```

might it help...

Comment: that's worked fine by using `view-souce`